# How to serve JSPs using Guice 3.0?

Tags: java, jsp, guice, guice-servlet

I'm trying to serve a JSP from Guice. I don't find any basic examples on how to do this!

My setup :

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.example.Bootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**org.example.Bootstrap** (something like...)

```
public class Bootstrap extends GuiceServletContextListener 
{
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector()
    {
        return Guice.createInjector(new org.example.BootstrapModule());
    }

}
```

**org.example.BootstrapModule** (something like...)

```
public class BootstrapModule extends ServletModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets()
    {
        // serve .JSPs
        bind(org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
        serveRegex("/.*\\.jsp").with(org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.class);

        // serve my controllers 
        bind(MainServlet.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
        serveRegex("/.*").with(MainServlet.class);
    }
}
```

In **MainServlet**, I do something like :

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").include(request, response);
```

or

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

or

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").include(request, response);
```

or

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

My **test.jsp** is in `webapp/test.jsp` (I use Maven).

It doesn't work! I always end up with errors like :

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File XXX not found
```

It seems the informations Guice passes to org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet are not the ones required for the JSPs to work.

What am I missing? Do I even have to specify org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet manually? What is required to correctly serve JSPs from Guice?

Answer (score 4):

It seems this is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=455).

As a workaround, some say you can compile the TRUNK of Guice. I also found that setting

```
request.setAttribute(org.apache.jasper.Constants.JSP_FILE, "/test.jsp");
```

before the forwarding also works.

But I have to run more tests to see what I'll use until Guice is fixed in a public release.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `Bootstrap#getModule()` to return a `new BootstrapModule()`.

```
@Override
protected Module getModule() {
    return new BootstrapModule();
}
```